# generate entity at runtime

Tags: java, code-generation

can anyone suggest me some jar file for generate annotation based entity from database like DAL4J.jar. Actually I have tried dal4j.jar but its generated entity with constructor and some unwanted lines in the entity. kindly help me to generate entity dynamically at run time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If runtime is not a restriction, you can use [hibernate tools](http://docs.jboss.org/jbosside/hibernate-tools/). Another alternative is aspect based libraries such [Spring Roo](http://www.springsource.org/spring-roo). Roo is tightly coupled with Spring but it is capable to generate almost everything at compile time.

Edit1:

> **Reverse Engineering:** The most powerful feature of Hibernate Tools is a database reverse engineering tool that can generate domain model classes and Hibernate mapping files, annotated EJB3 entity beans, HTML documentation or even an entire JBoss Seam application in seconds!
>
> ...
>
> **Ant task:** The Hibernate3 tools include a unified Ant task that allows you to run schema generation, mapping generation, or Java code generation as part of your build.
>
> ...
>
> **Maven task:** The Hibernate3 tools include a maven plugin that allows you to run schema generation, mapping generation, or Java code generation as part of your build.

My workflow has a maven plugin to generate entities.  You can choose one of the way to generate entities.

Comment: I have tried Roo also but its not compatible with my project. actually i am creating one Entity generator tool from database. I have tried many ways but all makes some problems. can you suggest me some API for generate annotation based entity. thank you..

Comment: RathaKrishna check my answer.